# Clickable triangles in a grid

Tags: html, css

Working on a small project where I'd like to have triangles in a grid. Ideally, I'd avoid images as I'd like each to contain dynamic content and be independently clickable.

I can get the 'look' of the grid, but I'm using positioning, which prevents one or the other right triangles from being clickable.

http://jsfiddle.net/dkjfc39m/2/ Here is what I'm going for (ish), just on a bigger scale.

HTML:

```
<div class="buttonBlock">
  <a class="buttonOdd"></a>
  <a class="buttonEven"></a>
  <a class="buttonOdd"></a>
  <a class="buttonEven"></a>
  <a class="buttonOdd"></a>
  <a class="buttonEven"></a>
</div>
<div class="buttonBlock">
  <a class="buttonOdd"></a>
  <a class="buttonEven"></a>
  <a class="buttonOdd"></a>
  <a class="buttonEven"></a>
  <a class="buttonOdd"></a>
  <a class="buttonEven"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.buttonOdd {
    border-bottom: 100px solid #0000ff;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}

.buttonEven {
    border-top: 100px solid #0000dd;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to do something like this

```css
.buttonBlock {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.buttonOdd {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #0000ff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 1;
}
.buttonEven {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #0000dd;
  position: initial;
  margin-top: -80px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Click on the Top or Bottom of the block</h3>
<div class="buttonBlock">
  <div class="buttonOdd" onclick="alert('Top side clicked')"></div>
  <div class="buttonEven" onclick="alert('Bottom side clicked')"></div>
</div>
```

Basically I turning the `buttonOdd` element at a `45deg` angle. Then I had the `buttonBlock` cover up the excess. Also I had to change it from a `a` tag to a `div` so it would render.

As you wanted it in a grid I will also included this as my new method may not work with yours.

```css
.buttonBlock {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.buttonOdd {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #0000ff;
  ;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

.buttonEven {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #0000dd;
  position: initial;
  margin-top: -80px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td,
tr {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<h3>Click on the Top or Bottom of a cell</h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="buttonBlock">
        <div class="buttonOdd" onclick="alert('Top side clicked on cell 1:1')"></div>
        <div class="buttonEven" onclick="alert('Bottom side clicked on cell 1:1')"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="buttonBlock">
        <div class="buttonOdd" onclick="alert('Top side clicked on cell 2:1')"></div>
        <div class="buttonEven" onclick="alert('Bottom side clicked on cell 2:1')"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="buttonBlock">
        <div class="buttonOdd" onclick="alert('Top side clicked on cell 3:1')"></div>
        <div class="buttonEven" onclick="alert('Bottom side clicked on cell 3:1')"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="buttonBlock">
        <div class="buttonOdd" onclick="alert('Top side clicked on cell 1:2')"></div>
        <div class="buttonEven" onclick="alert('Bottom side clicked on cell 1:2')"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="buttonBlock">
        <div class="buttonOdd" onclick="alert('Top side clicked on cell 2:2')"></div>
        <div class="buttonEven" onclick="alert('Bottom side clicked on cell 2:2')"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="buttonBlock">
        <div class="buttonOdd" onclick="alert('Top side clicked on cell 3:2')"></div>
        <div class="buttonEven" onclick="alert('Bottom side clicked on cell 3:2')"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="buttonBlock">
        <div class="buttonOdd" onclick="alert('Top side clicked on cell 1:3')"></div>
        <div class="buttonEven" onclick="alert('Bottom side clicked on cell 1:3')"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="buttonBlock">
        <div class="buttonOdd" onclick="alert('Top side clicked on cell 2:3')"></div>
        <div class="buttonEven" onclick="alert('Bottom side clicked on cell 2:3')"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="buttonBlock">
        <div class="buttonOdd" onclick="alert('Top side clicked on cell 3:3')"></div>
        <div class="buttonEven" onclick="alert('Bottom side clicked on cell 3:3')"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Drew242, If this answered your question, could you please accept it? If not I can try to correct it to your needs.

Comment: Awesome; yes - this is exactly what I was referring to. I really appreciate your time!

Comment: @Drew242, no problem.